# Logically Handling Lists

Tags: list, prolog, prolog-findall

I have a large number of facts within my program, listing developers and designers in a company, as well as previous projects, like so..

```
% project(Project Name,Year)
project(efnet, 2007).
% designer(Project Name, Name, Role)
designer(efnet, jane_cole, lead).
% developer(Project Name, Name, Role)
developer(efnet, alex_tobbs, architect).
```

I have also build a definition that displays a list of either designers or developers working on a project

```
% employees(Single Project, List of Employees
employees(Project, E)
```

What I want is to create a new definition that take a list of either designers or developers and displays a list of all the project titles they have BOTH worked on (P); like so..

```
% projects_of_all(List of Staff, List of Projects)
projects_of_all(S,P):- ...
```

I can do this easily with findall (or bagof) if I have to find the movies of a single person, but I am not sure how I would do this with a list of the employees. Can someone give me a helping hand with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the following which doesn't rely on the all-solutions built-ins like `findall`, `setof` or `bagof`:

```
% employees(Single Project, List of Employees
employees(Project, Employees) :-
    employees(Project, [], Employees).

employees(Project, Acc, Employees) :-
    (   designer(Project, Employee, _)
    ;   developer(Project, Employee, _)
    ),
    \+ member(Employee, Acc), !,
    employees(Project, [Employee|Acc], Employees).
employees(_Project, Employees, Employees).
```

This version accumulates a unique list of employees working on a project. Similarly, the implementation of your predicate `projects_of_all/2` can be as such:

```
% projects_of_all(List of Staff, List of Projects)
projects_of_all(Employees, Projects):- 
    projects_of_all(Employees, [], Projects).

projects_of_all(Employees, Acc, Projects):-
    \+ var(Employees),
    member(Employee, Employees),
    (   designer(Project, Employee, _)
    ;   developer(Project, Employee, _)
    ),
    \+ member(Project, Acc), !,
    projects_of_all(Employees, [Project|Acc], Projects).
projects_of_all(_Employees, Projects, Projects).
```

Note the guard subgoal `\+ var(Employees)`, as we don't want both arguments to the call to     `member(Employee, Employees)` to be completely unbound, which may cause an infinitely recursive expansion of variables in lists of ever-increasing length. Once we select an `Employee`, any associated `Project` is retrieved via `designer/3` *or* `developer/3` (leaving choicepoints), until a new `Project` not yet accumulated is found, at which time we go looking for more; until there aren't any more, in which case we stop (the 2nd clause is the base case).

While this is probably inefficient relative to any internal (i.e., native, non-interpreted) implementation of `findall`, `setof` or `bagof`, it serves to demonstrate an approach which is intended to help you understand the solution using accumulator methods.

If you require the use of an all-solutions built-in, you could implement `projects_of_all/2` as such:

```
% projects_of_all(List of Staff, List of Projects)
projects_of_all(Employees, Projects):- 
    findall(Project, 
        (   member(Employee, Employees), 
            (   designer(Project, Employee, _)
            ;   developer(Project, Employee, _)
            )
        ), ProjectsBag),
    sort(ProjectsBag, Projects).
```

Note that `setof` and `bagof` will backtrack to give you alternatives, but you want all projects in a list accumulated, which is the behaviour of `findall`. Presumably, though, you don't want duplicates, so calling `sort/2` on the result as shown removes duplicates to give you a set.

**EDIT:** The OP changed (clarified) the question after I had written this, which called for a completely different answer (explanation below):

```
% projects_of_all(List of Staff, List of Projects)
projects_of_all(Employees, CommonProjects):- 
    % find the projects of every employee in the input list
    employee_projects(Employees, EmployeeProjects),
    % find the intersection of all projects (common projects)
    recursive_val_intersect(EmployeeProjects, CommonProjects).

employee_projects([], []).
employee_projects([Employee|Employees], [Projects|Rem]) :-
    findall(Project, 
        (   designer(Project, Employee, _)
        ;   developer(Project, Employee, _)
        ),
    ProjectsBag),
    sort(ProjectsBag, Projects),
    employee_projects(Employees, Rem).

recursive_val_intersect([L|Ls], Intersect) :-
    recursive_val_intersect(Ls, L, Intersect).
recursive_val_intersect([], Acc, Acc).
recursive_val_intersect([L0|Ls], L1, Intersect) :-
    intersection(L0, L1, NewL),
    recursive_val_intersect(Ls, NewL, Intersect).
```

`employee_projects/2` is used to build a list of lists of projects that each `Employee` in the input list had worked on. Note that it uses the `findall/3` solution strategy I used earlier. The second predicate, `recursive_val_intersect/2,3`, determines the intersection of all the project lists, as this indicates the projects that every employee has **worked on together**. This is different to the above solution which just seeks all projects worked on by all employees in the input list, which is what I'd aimed at.

Note that `recursive_val_intersect/3` above relies on the SWI-PROLOG set-intersection predicate [`intersection/3`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=intersection/3), which takes lists with no duplicates (hence the use of `sort/2` to construct the input lists in `employee_projects/2`).

Comment: Sorry to be a nuisance but I have come across a small problem. I wanted the problem to work so that it would return a list of projects that ALL staff members in a list had worked on, whereas this returns a list that either may have worked on.

Comment: Your alteration (clarification) of the problem changes the semantics such that the solution is significantly different. I'll add an edit with a proposed solution anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Try something similar to this, where `Es` is the list of employees:

```
setof(P, E^(member(E, Es), employee(P, E)), Projects)
```

The `E^` is an existential quantifier.

Comment: I've just tried it and says "Error: Out of global stack". I should note that in employees Project is a single project.

Comment: I made that one up, it means `E` is an employee working on project `P`. With `employees/2` it would be more complicated.